# Start a script on ganeti node after instance is started or migrated

Tags: kvm-virtualization, startup-scripts, ganeti

There is a ganeti cluster. Is there any way to run script on ganeti node after some instance is start running on that node?
In both situations - starting from scratch, and migrating live from another host.

It's possible to do it "automated" way(excluding modifying sources)? Only idea which i have is to invoke a trigger from instance to node to run script - but i know that it's not good way.

Are there any scripts running for instances in node context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You want to use `hooks` for this, as outlined in the [docs](http://docs.ganeti.org/ganeti/2.16/html/hooks.html):

> In order to allow customisation of operations, Ganeti runs scripts in sub-directories of @SYSCONFDIR@/ganeti/hooks. These sub-directories are named $hook-$phase.d, where $phase is either pre or post and $hook matches the directory name given for a hook (e.g. cluster-verify-post.d or node-add-pre.d).
>
> This is similar to the /etc/network/ structure present in Debian for network interface handling.

(If you're running into specific problems or need additional help, please let me know, I'm glad to help.)